# process is termianted due to stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, database, nodes

trying to run a function that would remove a character from a list of lists but getting a stackoverflow exception

in the program

```
        public static void removeChar(World World)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("what character would you like to remove");
            string cName = Console.ReadLine();
            World.RemoveChar(cName);
        }
```

in the class world

```
        public void RemoveChar(string cName)
        {
            RemoveChar(cName);
        }
```

in the class party

```
        public void RemoveChar(string cName)
        {
            Node<Character> temp = Characters;
            while (!temp.HasNext())
            {
                if (temp.GetNext().GetValue().getName() == cName)
                {
                    temp.SetNext(temp.GetNext().GetNext());
                }
                temp = temp.GetNext();

            }
            if (temp.GetValue().getName() == cName)
            {
                temp = null;
            }

        }
```

when trying to remove a chracter im getting a stack overflow error

[the error code im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsstZ.png)

side note : this is not a syntax error but an error in cmd incase it isnt clear

the properties of the class world

```
    private string name;
    private Node<Party> Partylist;
```

the properties of the class party

```
    private string pName;
    private Node<Character> Characters;
```

Comment: [Tutorial: Debug C# code - Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) or [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 2):

`World.RemoveChar()` seemingly by your example anyway.
Is just calling itself resulting in an infinite callstack until it overflows.

Comment: what should i change?

Comment: To add to that comment, in your second `RemoveChar` method, your code means `this.RemoveChar()`, and I think you expect `party.RemoveChar()` instead. `party` is an instance of your `Party` class.

Comment: You would need to as @K.A. says, call `Party.RemoveChar` if you have an instance of your Party class inside your world class you'll have to call RemoveChar on that instance. if you add more of your code, so we can see where the Party is I'll be happy to add to my answer.